# ¿Cómo lograr traer los registros que se encuentren dentro de 2 fechas? (Spring)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

Tal como lo dice el título de la pregunta, estoy buscando lograr traer los registros que se encuentren entre 2 fechas.

Esto es lo que he desarrollado de momento:

**Entidad 'Pedido'**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pedidos")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Pedido implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "fecha")
    private Date fecha;

    @Column(name = "cantidad_total")
    private int cantidadTotal;

    @Column(name = "precio_total")
    private BigDecimal precioTotal;
```

}

**Repositorio**:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE fecha >= :desde AND fecha <= :hasta" , nativeQuery 
= true)
List<Pedido> findPedidosEntreFechas(Date desde, Date hasta);
```

**Servicio:**

```
@Transactional
    public List<Pedido> findPedidosEntreFechas(Date desde, Date hasta) throws Exception {
        try {
            return pedidoRepository.findPedidosEntreFechas(desde, hasta);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Controlador:**

```
@GetMapping("buscarPedidos/{desde}/{hasta}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getPedidosEntreFechas(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date desde,
                                                   @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date hasta) {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(pedidoService.findPedidosEntreFechas(desde, hasta));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("{\"message\": \"Error. Please try again later.\"}");
        }
    }
```

En la **base de datos** tengo 3 registros:

- ID: 1, fecha: 2021-06-03, otros datos...
- ID: 2, fecha: 2021-06-03, otros datos...
- ID: 3, fecha: 2021-06-04, otros datos...

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente **endpoint** en Postman, obtengo como resultado un **arreglo vacío**:

http://localhost:9000/api/v1/pedidos/buscarPedidos/2021-06-03/2021-06-03

Ahora, si ejecuto este otro, obtengo como resultado los **3 registros**

http://localhost:9000/api/v1/pedidos/buscarPedidos/2021-06-03/2021-06-04

Entonces el **problema** que estoy teniendo (el que veo a la vista por lo menos, quizás haya otros) es que no puedo traer los registros cuyas fechas 'desde' y 'hasta' sean iguales, es decir, los pedidos que realicé en **UN DÍA**.

Desde ya agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda !

Comment: Te recomiendo no usar NUNCA java.util.Date, sino java.time.LocalDate

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de datos tiene la columna en la base de datos? ¿qué base de datos estás usando? ¿cómo insertas un nuevo registro? Si solo necesitas el día, sin horas, minutos ni segundos, quizás tengas que establecer un tipo específico en la base de datos para que no te almacene más precisión de la necesaria.

Answer (score 1):

La clase java.util.Date guarda hasta los milisegundos, por tanto cuando estás buscando con los parámetros `2021-06-03/2021-06-03`, realmente estás buscando así:

`WHERE date <= 2021-06-03 00:00:00.000 AND date >= 2021-06-03 00:00:00.000`

Es decir, estás buscando fechas que sean EXACTAMENTE (hasta el milisegundo) la que le has pasado.

Si usas `LocalDate` podrías hacer con la fecha final algo como

```
hasta = hasta.plusDays(1); //es inmutable, se crea una nueva instancia
```